# Excel: Adding numeric value to yes/no

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a spreadsheet for some calendar orders that I have organised.

Currently I have a column which has the unit price of $14.50, then I have a column for quantity (number of orders placed), then a subtotal (unit price * Quantity) and finally a paid column, which is a simple dropdown box of yes || no.

The formulas that I have created thus far are working. But now that I have gone to print I want to keep track of payments. So, what I would like is when someone has paid to subtract their subtotal (unit price * quantity) from the grand total. So, in the paid column of yes || no, when yes is selected it subtracts the subtotal from the grand total.

I was wondering if someone could find a solution for this. A far as I can figure out the formula needs to consist of adding a value to yes and no, but also somehow adding and factoring in the subtotal value. I am quite unsure of this, so this is why I am seeking help.

*note. The yes and no selection is a range that spans across 2 columns. the first range is from H5:H62. the second range is from Q5:Q62

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to modify the *grand total* calculation, to only `SUM` the unpaid subtotals, with a conditional sum ([`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe) or [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/article/SUMIFS-function-9dd6179e-cced-41dd-ac38-08fdf5b929e5)). e.g.:

```
SUMIFS(C5:C62; H5:H62; "<>Yes"; Q5:Q62; "<>Yes")
```

Where `C` is the subtotals column.
I'm not sure if you mean that both `H` and `Q` have the same Yes/No values, but this should serve as a start.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIFS(Subtotal_Range, Paid_Column, "<>Yes")
```

Sums your subtotals if the Paid column does not equal YES